# Julia 0.3.0: librmath-julia-dev not installable

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, julia

I am trying to install julia 0.3.0 from julianightlies on Ubuntu 12.04. I can install 0.2.1 just fine. I added

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/staticfloat/julianightlies/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/staticfloat/julianightlies/ubuntu precise main
```

to my /etc/apt/sources.list manually. When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install julia
```

I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 julia : Depends: librmath-julia-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit:
After [enabling all repos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) it still gives the same error.

Here is what I get when I try to add the repo via the command line:

```
USER:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:staticfloat/julianightlies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 128, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (35, 'gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.')
```

When I download the .deb file and open it in the package manager I get the warning:

```
depdendency is not satisfiable librmath-julia-dev
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue ended up being that I also needed to add ppa:staticfloat/julia-deps to my sources.list, as described [here](http://julialang.org/downloads/).

My additional issues arose from some internet configurations imposed by my network, causing attempts to add ppa's via command line to fail. Adding them manually worked fine.